# Different space in Chrome to Firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, html-table, alignment

I've managed to get the table in the header on the following page to line up perfectly at the bottom in Google Chrome but in Firefox and Internet Explorer there is white space at the bottom.

http://alisonkeane.com.au/demo/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set line height , 
`tr {line-height:30px}`

Comment: thanks for the quick reply.  can you please give me a bit more information, I'm quite new to this.

Comment: if line height is not specified, browser automatically set line height, so it has different value in different browser. Setting line height is good practice to make our site browser friendly.